# SQL database schema design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I want to design a database schema. I have several channels (Channel_ID VARCHAR) and timestamps that correspond to the time when the measurements for the channels have been made (Timestamp DATETIME).

What would be an intelligent schema to save the time-series data that every channel records? I only come up with something like this but this seems to be quite bad since the Values column contains all the values...

```
MEASUREMENTS
Channel_ID VARCHAR | Timestamp DATETIME | Values ???
```

How would I do this correctly?

EDIT: The number of values can be in the thousands.

Comment: What are the "Values" - Presumably more than 1 value, if so you would create a row per individual value, identifying its type via a value_type table

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In the meantime I figured out another solution. I could create a second table with multiple columns and each column in this table has a unique measurement id (that is the channel_id combined with the timestamp). Each of these columns contains all the measurement values of the particular measurement. What do you think about that?

Comment: It is almost always better to go down (rows) than across (columns) - how much so depends of the types of queries you want to run - doing math on a set of rows is trivial, doing it on *n* columns is not.  You certainly don't want to have a design that requires the creation of new columns with variable names.

Comment: Suppose I store the values in a row which is identified by an individual measurement id (that is the channel_id combined with the timestamp). Since these measurements are recorded in milliseconds I want to be able to select only those values that are in a certain range (for example 0.000 to 0.240 (in ms)). Would this be possible? I don't know a query that can find only the first x values of a row...

Comment: The problem is that the measurements are not perfectly continuous. It can be possible that some values are missing. That means I would require something like a milliseconds column to keep track of the measurements... or am I wrong?

Comment: If timestamp is a datetime or an arbitrary integer value you can easily pull off a range between 2 values, they don't need to be contiguous

Comment: Hmm maybe we don't talk about the same thing here... I have something like this: measurement_id (20160501SA0FD3FC2). For each id I have a lot of time-series values such das 0.12 (at 0.000), 0.11 (at 0.001), 0.14 (at 0.003), 0.13 (at 0.006), ... if I have the values (0,12, 0.11, 0.14, 0.13) in one row, how would I be able to find out, when the measurements were taken (0.000, 0.001, 0.003, 0.006)?

Comment: Hmm I could possibly store them as tuples... do you think this is a good idea? Btw. feel free to post an answer. I will certainly upvote and accept it. I really appreciate this conversation.

Comment: a table with [measure_id | time | value] columns sound best.  You would not have the time value as a column.

Comment: That should do the trick. Thank you I forgot that I can have the same value for measure_id in different rows. This looks like a nice solution to my problem. Have a nice day and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the creation of a measurements table in addition to your channels table.  Each row would have a unique key (primary key), a foreign key that references a row within the channels table (to associate a reading with a channel), a timestamp, and any other data regarding that specific reading.

With this setup, you could have multiple measurements for a specific channel and you could select them by doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM measurements
WHERE channel_id = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would this solution require me to save the actual measurement values as arrays? Or to be more precise: Would the values for one channel_id be saved in one single cell?

Comment: Each measurement would be an individual row within the measurements table.  Following 1NF, we want an individual cell to only contain one thing.

Comment: A cell being a field in database terminology.  Here is an example:
Row 1: Measurement ID = 1, Channel ID = 5, measurement = 1000
Row 2: Measurement ID = 2, Channel ID = 5, measurement = 3000.

Sorry, I don't fully grasp the measurements and channels, but I tried to set this up best to the extent of my understanding.  

When you run a command like the one in the above answer, it will return 2 rows, a row for each individual measurement, both for the channel with the ID of 5.

Comment: Would this not be problematic if there can be different numbers of values in each row? But what you suggest was actually my initial idea... The question would of couse also be how to add the values to the table (if the number of values differs for each row)...

Comment: What exactly does an individual measurement contain?  I'm not really sure I'm understanding.  The method I proposed should prevent non atomic data assuming a measurement is atomic and can be stored in a row.

Comment: In the question I mentioned Channel_ID VARCHAR | Timestamp DATETIME | Values. This could for example be: "id_32" | 07/31/2016 | 0.34, 0.53, 0.78, 0.12, ... Thus I am not sure if your suggestion would work. I think the best way would be to use an array inside a single cell for the values. Then your approach should work.